# Hide button on tabs in Kofax KTM

Tags: kofax

Hello we are using a script in KTM to make the button on the validation form invisible. The project has several classes and depending on the class we hide the buttons.

`ValidationForm.Buttons.ItemByName ("btnDBFuzzy_2"). Visible = False`

Now we have to use tabs in the project. I'm looking silly, but can't find the way to control the buttons on the tabs.
Maybe someone here has an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your button is now on a different tab, you would need to make use of the following syntax: `ValidationForm.Tabs.ItemByName("Tab A")`. The same applies to all other controls.

Comment: Many thanks, that was what i searched for.